# Looking for a specific hop rhizome

Tags: hops, growing-hops, rhizome

Looking for a Medusa rhizome or a Canadian Red Vine rhizome. Any help would much appreciated! Cheers!

Comment: It also depends on where you live, because rhizome is not likely to be shipped to other countries.  So it is better to find a store in your country.

Answer (score 1):

Medusa is just a commercialized named for multihead. You can get them, as well as Canadian Red Vine (currently sold-out) from Great Lakes Hops.

https://www.greatlakeshops.com/store/p113/MultiheadNeomexicana

Answer (score 0):

Freshops stocks the Canadian Red Vine https://freshops.com/shop/rhizomes/canadian-redvine-rhizomes/

Medusa, on the other hand, is not as far as I know commercially available.